# Finding the mode of a randomly generated array of 10 numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to make this program

```
public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 10;
        int sum =0;

        int[] numArray= new int [SIZE];

        for (int c=0; c < SIZE; c++)
        {
            numArray[c]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
            System.out.print( numArray[c]+   " ");

            sum+=numArray[c];
        }

        System.out.println("\nSum of all numbers is " + sum);
        System.out.println("\n Mean of numbers is " + (sum) / 5);
    }
}
```

Calculate the mode of the randomly generated array.

I've seen source codes posted where they use a seperate method called computemode, but I don't kno where to place this second method within my code. I'm sorry, I am very very green when it comes to programming. I'm being taught Java as my first language and so far its overwhelming.

If someone could post the syntax with detailed instruction/explanation I'd be so grateful.

Comment: An array can have more than one mode. Do you need to report all values that have maximum frequency in the array or just one? Do you need to report locations?

Answer (score 0):

The mode is quite easy to compute.  One way, assuming your inputs are bounded, is to simply have an array that tracks the number of occurrences of each number:

```
int[] data; //your data bounded by 0 and MAX_VALUE
int[] occurrences = new int[MAX_VALUE+1];

for ( int datum : data ) {
    occurrences[newNumber]++;
}
```

Then figure out the index(es) in occurrences that has the highest value.

```
int maxOccurrences = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int mode = -1;

for ( int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++ ) {
    if ( occurrences[i] > maxOccurrences ) {
        maxOccurrences = occurrences[i];
        mode = i;
    }
}
```

You would have to adjust this to handle multiple modes.

Comment: You could just set `maxOccurences` to `0`, since nothing can possibly occur a negative number of times.